# Can we synonymize [tags] and [tagging] on meta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

As of now, we have both [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) as tags on meta, and I don't see any convincing reason to keep both.

Currently, there are **6** questions tagged with [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), versus **52** tagged with [tags](/questions/tagged/tags). **4** questions are tagged with both. As such, it would probably be best to make [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) the main tag, and synonymize [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) to it.

Comment: I'm inclined to go with tagging rather than tags, since the questions asked are about the action of tagging, and not about the actual tags mechanism.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha For what it's worth, [MSO has](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tags/synonyms) "tags" as the main and "tagging" (and a few other things) as synonyms.

Comment: Well, wouldn't want to break the streak. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) was removed from all posts, and synonymized to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).

- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) was removed from 6 posts.
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) was added to 2 posts.
- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) now synonyms to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).